# js function with n number of parenthesis

Tags: javascript, web

How to define a function in Javascript with n number of parenthesis. For example if we have a sum function , we should be able to call it as below

```
sum(2)(1)(5);
```

and it should return 8, where the number of parenthesis can be 1 to n.

Comment: This looks like a chaining function. You might need to return a recursive function. I don't think it is even possible now in JavaScript.

Comment: 1. This is called a _curried function_. 2. It's not possible to do exactly what you want, since, basically, a curried function would return another function until you've gotten all arguments, e.g., the "uncurried" version of what you posted would be `sum(a, b, c)` but you cannot have a curried function "know" when to stop returning functions aside from putting a limit.

Comment: Why not just pass an array of N values to a function then loop through each item in the array?

Comment: @vlaz , i thought the same . i used curryied function to figure it out but it wasn't really working though not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

This should be close enough

```
function sum(x) {  
   var _b = x;

   var f = function(n) {
     _b += n;
     return f;
   }

   f.valueOf = function() {
     return _b;
   }

   return f; 
}

console.log( sum(1)(2)(3) + 1 );
```

Note that the best you can do still requires a trick to get a value from the function that just has to return another function (so that you can call it again).

The trick consists in defining `valueOf`/`toString` so that a value of the internal buffer is returned when necessary.

Comment: I am unable to make the `.toString()` thing, thought about using class, but didn't work out.

Comment: @Wiktor Zychla why that code is not working without +1?

Comment: @Arun if you use the result in a mathematical expression, then the result of `valueOf` is used for the conversion. So you could, in theory, do a `+ 0` instead but it's still a bit of a hack.

Comment: @Arun: Because the return value of a bare `sum(1)(2)(3)` is still a function and it has to be since you would possibly like to call it again. The `valueOf` is the trick I talk about, it makes this function aware of carrying a value. You could override `toString` that should make it `console.log` friendly, however, it would not work with `+1` as you would expect.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not exactly possible. The problem is in that if you want to chain functions, each has to return a function.

Now you want the final call to return a number, but how could the function know when to return the final value instead of a function?

You could however pass any number of arguments to a function, and access them with [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

```js
function sum(/*num1, num2, num3, ..., numN*/) {
  return [].reduce.call(arguments, function(sum, num) {
    return sum + num;
  }, 0);
}
console.log(sum(1, 2, 3));
```

Or alternately, store the sum in the outer scope and never return the value.

```js
var sum = 0;
function add(num) {
  sum += num;
  return add;
}

add(1)(2)(3);
console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript a value cannot be both a function and a number at the same time, so you somehow need to indicate that you want to have the number after the last argument was passed to it.

One way to do this, is to let the function return the sum value when you pass it no argument (an extra pair of parentheses):

```
sum(2)(3)(6)()
```

This you can implement like this:

```js
function sum(a) {
    return b => b === undefined ? a : sum(a+b);
}

var a = sum(2)(3)(6)();

console.log(a);
```

An alternative, as suggested also by Wictor, is to use the returned function in way that it will coerce to a number. By defining an appropriate `valueOf` method you can then define what that number should be when this happens.

This can be combined with the previous method, so that you can actually choose how to get the number value:

```js
function sum(a) {
    var f = b => b === undefined ? a : sum(a+b);
    f.valueOf = _ => a;
    return f;
}

// method 1:
console.log(sum(2)(3)(6)());
// method 2:
console.log(+sum(2)(3)(6));
```

Note that to coerce to a value to a number, you can use the unitary `+`.

With `Object.assign` this can be rewritten in *functional programming* style:

```js
function sum(a) {
    return Object.assign(b => b === undefined ? a : sum(a+b), { valueOf: _ => a });
}

// method 1:
console.log(sum(2)(3)(6)());
// method 2:
console.log(+sum(2)(3)(6));
```